# Is the launch of an on-page modal considered a "change of context" when considering WCAG?

Tags: web, popup, modal-dialog, accessibility

I have an accessibility requirement that states:

"Verify that, upon input within the stated UI component, the user input does not force a change of context unless the user has been previously advised through messaging.
-- Change of context = That no change occurs in the user agent, viewport, focus of that particular element, or content changes that impact meaning."

WCAG give an example of a failure to be a "pop-up window". To non-developers, I am thinking that a on-screen modal could be perceived as a pop-up window. Does anyone else agree?

We literally have dozens of modals all over the site I am working on and need to make sure before I start throwing aria-labels all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a change of context. In operating systems, this is communicated to users through the user of the ellipsis (...) at the end of the name e.g. a button with the text "Save..." can be expected to popup a dialog, whereas a button with the text "Save" will be expected to just save.

You can use `aria-haspopup="true"` on a button, in combination with a convention like the ellipsis to convey this in an accessible manner. http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-haspopup

Comment: I have a follow up question. Once the modal is open would an aria property then have to be put on the buttons that _close_ the pop-up. The action of closing the pop up seems like it would be another change of context.